# Confused about assertNull behaviour with HashTable

Tags: java, junit

During some JUnit fixing I found this line of code:

```
Assert.assertNull(lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry));
```

if I inspect the operation `lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry)` the result is always null but the `assertNull` fails nevertheless.

When I change the code to:

```
 Entry lEntry = lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry);
 Assert.assertNull(lEntry);
```

everything works fine.

I am a little bit confused. Could you tell me why I get two different results with the above lines of code?

Thx a lot...

Comment: In what context is the inspection taking place? What's the rest of the test case?

Comment: what do you mean with context? I inspect it with ctrl+alt+i Eclipse IDE.

Comment: That's what I meant. This behavior is odd, and all the information surrounding the call is useful.

Comment: Is the HashTable accessed by more than one thread?

Comment: Can you hover the `assertNull` in the compound statement and verify what the signature is? What happens if you cast the value to `(Entry)`?

Comment: Are you inside a try/catch block by any chance?

Comment: Can you break right before this assert and inspect `lAllEntryById.contains`?

Comment: In my answer, he said that it's returning false.

Comment: contains returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines have identical result in assertion:

```
Assert.assertNull(lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry));
```

And this

```
Entry lEntry = lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry);
Assert.assertNull(lEntry);
```

The problem might be caused by:

1. forgetting to clear table before adding new element (then `put` returns old object)
2. you could sequentially execute 1 statement after another

To avoid this I would suggest this experiment:

```
lAllEntryById = new HashTable<EntryId, Entry>(); // ensure nothing effects it
Assert.assertNull(lAllEntryById.put(lEntry.getId(), lEntry));
```

Comment: sorry I dont get it. As you descriped the result of lAllEntryById.put is in both cases null. But the first assertNull is false and the second is true. WTF???

Comment: I've added experiment to do to avoid issues mentioned

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29

> Returns:
>       the previous value of the specified key in this hashtable, or null if it did not have one

Verify that you're are not inserting a value in the hashmap with the same key before.

Try to do :

```
Assert.assertFalse(lAllEntryById.contains(lEntry.getId());
```

Before your assert.

Comment: The OP appears to have read the Javadoc. He's asking about an odd case where separating the return value out into its own variable changes the behavior.

Comment: I mean that it's pretty oblivious that a value has been inserted before the assert, so the question is how this value was inserted before, and we need more code for that.

Comment: there is no value with that key. I dont understand why the two ways I call the assertNull give me different results...

Comment: Aren't doing the 2 assert one after the other ?
How are you checking that the key has no value ? If you didn't try, you should print the value before the assert to be sure.

Comment: I edited my answer, check what the contains method of the hashtable returns.